# Memory ordering in boost::lockfree:queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, atomic, lock-free

Consider the following structure:

```
struct T { 
 ~T() { delete[] buff; }
  int* buff = nullptr; };
T* t = new T();
auto queue = boost::lockfree::queue<T*>(0);
// Thread A
t->buff = int[10];
queue.push(t);
// Thread Z
T* t = nullptr;
while(true)
  if(queue.pop(t))
    delete t; // Is this OK? If not, what kind of synchronization I need to make it OK?
```

The general problem is that different threads (A to Y) work together on shared pointers (not std::shared_ptr). At some point, no one but Thread A works with a pointer `t` and Thread A sees everything others have done to `*t`, so Thread A can safely call `delete t`. Instead, it pushes `t` into a queue and Thread Z pops from the queue and does the `delete t`. The question is how do we make sure Thread Z sees the last value assigned to `t->buff`? Is there any synchronization in `boost::lockfree::queue` that guarantees this? or we need to do something ourselves (what)?

Comment: TL:DR: is `queue.push` a release operation on the queue entry, and is `queue.pop(t)` an acquire operation on the queue entry?  I'd assume yes, but the docs should say.

Comment: `push` uses the `head`, and `pop` uses the `tail`. The implementation even uses `std::memory_order_seq_cst`. But I don't think that necessarily guarantees what I am looking for.

Comment: @Koosha, why doesn't it guarantee what you're looking for? The SC CAS is both an acquire and a release operation so the non-atomic write to `buff` is a visible side effect after popping in thread Z.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is safe! You have sole ownership over the value popped from the queue. `push` has to use `memory_order_release` (or stronger) and `pop` has to use `memory_order_acquire` (or stronger), because otherwise the implementation would be completely useless (you could do *nothing* with the pointer you just popped from the queue). I haven't checked the code, but you say that the implementation uses `memory_order_seq_cst`, so you should be good!